# c# UWP Timer (delayed text)

Tags: c#, timer, uwp

```
String[] vals = s.Split(';');
String o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];
if (vals[0] == "225.0" && vals[1] == "225.0" && vals[2] == "225.0")
{
    updateText.Text = "Something wrong with the connection. Please try again."; 

}
else
{   
    updateText.Text = "Connection okay. You're ready to start your exercise.\nProceed to Step 3.";
}
```

I have connected my rfduino with my MPU6050. If the connection has an error, my xyz will show 225.0 constantly. Otherwise, the values will constantly change due to me moving the MPU6050.

This is my current code. But what I want to implement is, if my x,y,z values are showing "225.0" for 3 seconds, it will display a text.

if my x,y,z values are showing different values (other than 225.0) for 3 seconds, it will displays another text.

how do I do that ?

Comment: "If my ... values are showing ... for 3 seconds..." I don't see anything in your code that would make the values ever show anything different. Is the code you posted in a loop or a timer delegate or something?

Comment: Is in a loop. I connected my rfduino with MPU6050. If my device is connected properly, my xyz values will change due to me moving the MPU6050. However, if it is not connected properly, my xyz will show 225.0 constantly

Comment: I saw you had asked this issue on the MSDN, please check the [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d4de1d3-47d9-490e-a4e5-7ff11da92245/uwpc-dispatchertimer?forum=wpdevelop).